# Boost/Asio socket file

Tags: c++, boost-asio

In past i wrote simple tcp server using boost library and Below code working properly.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class session
  : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(tcp::socket socket)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
  {
  }

  void start()
  {
    do_read();
  }

private:
  void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_write(length);
          }
        });
  }

  void do_write(std::size_t length)
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(data_, length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  enum { max_length = 1024 };
  char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    do_accept();
  }

private:
  void do_accept()
  {
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
          }

          do_accept();
        });
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: async_tcp_echo_server <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_context io_context;

    server s(io_context, std::atoi(argv[1]));

    io_context.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Now i want to use socket file named "mysocket" and use it instead of ip/port. And i changed only below lines. I also expect the "mysocket" file to be created automatically from the following line. So i didnt create it manually.

```
  server(boost::asio::io_context& io_context, short port)
    : acceptor_(io_context, boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::endpoint("mysocket"))
  {
    do_accept();
  }

boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor_;
```

But i doenst compile and gives below error. How can i fix it?

```
main.cpp: In member function ‘void server::do_accept()’:
main.cpp:67:27: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::async_accept(server::do_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>)’
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   75 |           do_accept();
   76 |         });
      |         ~~                 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1398:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Protocol1, class Executor1, class AcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<AcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol1, Executor1>&, AcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<std::is_convertible<Protocol, Protocol1>::value>::type) [with Protocol1 = Protocol1; Executor1 = Executor1; AcceptToken = AcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 1398 |   async_accept(basic_socket<Protocol1, Executor1>& peer,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1398:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:67:27: note:   ‘server::do_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’ is not derived from ‘boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol, Executor>’
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   74 | 
      |                            
   75 |           do_accept();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~     
   76 |         });
      |         ~~                 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1531:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Executor1, class AcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<AcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket<Protocol, Executor1>&, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type&, AcceptToken&&) [with Executor1 = Executor1; AcceptToken = AcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 1531 |   async_accept(basic_socket<protocol_type, Executor1>& peer,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1531:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:67:27: note:   ‘server::do_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’ is not derived from ‘boost::asio::basic_socket<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol, Executor1>’
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   74 | 
      |                            
   75 |           do_accept();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~     
   76 |         });
      |         ~~                 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1679:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(MoveAcceptToken&&) [with MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 1679 |   async_accept(
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1679:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1679:3: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:53,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/execution_context.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:409,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/system_context.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/system_executor.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/system_executor.hpp:671,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/associated_executor.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/any_completion_handler.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::async_accept<MoveAcceptToken>(MoveAcceptToken&&) [with MoveAcceptToken = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]’:
main.cpp:67:27:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1209:20:   required for the satisfaction of ‘completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void(boost::system::error_code, typename Protocol::socket::rebind_executor<Executor>::other)>’ [with MoveAcceptToken = server::do_accept::._anon_255; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1212:3:   in requirements with ‘T&& t’ [with Signatures = {void()}; T = server::do_accept::._anon_255]
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1214:37: note: the required expression ‘async_initiate<T, Signatures ...>(boost::asio::detail::initiation_archetype<Signatures ...>{}, t)’ is invalid
 1214 |     async_initiate<T, Signatures...>(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
 1215 |         detail::initiation_archetype<Signatures...>{}, t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1plus: note: set ‘-fconcepts-diagnostics-depth=’ to at least 2 for more detail
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1936:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Executor1, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(const Executor1&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<(boost::asio::is_executor<Executor1>::value || boost::asio::execution::is_executor<T>::value)>::type) [with Executor1 = Executor1; MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 1936 |   async_accept(const Executor1& ex,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:1936:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class Executor1, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::async_accept<Executor1, MoveAcceptToken>(const Executor1&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<(boost::asio::is_executor<Executor>::value || boost::asio::execution::is_executor<T>::value)>::type) [with Executor1 = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; MoveAcceptToken = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’:
main.cpp:67:27:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1209:20:   required for the satisfaction of ‘completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void(boost::system::error_code, typename Protocol::socket::rebind_executor<typename boost::asio::constraint<(boost::asio::is_executor<Executor1>::value || boost::asio::execution::is_executor<T>::value), Executor1>::type>::other)>’ [with MoveAcceptToken = void; Executor1 = server::do_accept::._anon_255; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]
main.cpp:67:27: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘struct boost::asio::constraint<false, server::do_accept()::<lambda(boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)> >’
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   74 | 
      |                            
   75 |           do_accept();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~     
   76 |         });
      |         ~~                 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2035:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class ExecutionContext, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(ExecutionContext&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type) [with ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext; MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 2035 |   async_accept(ExecutionContext& context,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2035:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2035:3: note: constraints not satisfied
main.cpp: In substitution of ‘template<class ExecutionContext, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::async_accept<ExecutionContext, MoveAcceptToken>(ExecutionContext&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type) [with ExecutionContext = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; MoveAcceptToken = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’:
main.cpp:67:27:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1209:20:   required for the satisfaction of ‘completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void(boost::system::error_code, typename Protocol::socket::rebind_executor<typename ExecutionContext::executor_type>::other)>’ [with MoveAcceptToken = void; ExecutionContext = server::do_accept::._anon_255; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]
main.cpp:67:27: error: no type named ‘executor_type’ in ‘struct server::do_accept()::<lambda(class boost::system::error_code, boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket)>’
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   74 | 
      |                            
   75 |           do_accept();
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~     
   76 |         });
      |         ~~                 
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2211:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type&, MoveAcceptToken&&) [with MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 2211 |   async_accept(endpoint_type& peer_endpoint,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2211:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2211:3: note: constraints not satisfied
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_type_requirements.hpp:53,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/execution_context.hpp:18,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/execution_context.hpp:409,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/detail/scheduler.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/system_context.hpp:19,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/impl/system_executor.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/system_executor.hpp:671,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/associated_executor.hpp:24,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio/any_completion_handler.hpp:28,
                 from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp: In substitution of ‘template<class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::async_accept<MoveAcceptToken>(boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<boost::asio::local::stream_protocol>::endpoint_type&, MoveAcceptToken&&) [with MoveAcceptToken = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]’:
main.cpp:67:27:   required from here
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1209:20:   required for the satisfaction of ‘completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void(boost::system::error_code, typename Protocol::socket::rebind_executor<Executor>::other)>’ [with MoveAcceptToken = void; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol]
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1212:3:   in requirements with ‘T&& t’ [with Signatures = {void()}; T = void]
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/async_result.hpp:1212:3: error: forming reference to void
 1212 |   requires(T&& t)
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1213 |   {
      |   ~
 1214 |     async_initiate<T, Signatures...>(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1215 |         detail::initiation_archetype<Signatures...>{}, t);
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 1216 |   };
      |   ~
In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2500:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class Executor1, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(const Executor1&, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<(boost::asio::is_executor<Executor1>::value || boost::asio::execution::is_executor<T>::value)>::type) [with Executor1 = Executor1; MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 2500 |   async_accept(const Executor1& ex, endpoint_type& peer_endpoint,
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2500:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:67:27: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |           }
      |           ~                
   74 | 
   75 |           do_accept();

   76 |         });

In file included from /usr/local/include/boost/asio.hpp:43,
                 from main.cpp:5:
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2603:3: note: candidate: ‘template<class ExecutionContext, class MoveAcceptToken>  requires  completion_token_for<MoveAcceptToken, void()> auto boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::async_accept(ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::basic_socket_acceptor<Protocol, Executor>::endpoint_type&, MoveAcceptToken&&, typename boost::asio::constraint<std::is_convertible<ExecutionContext&, boost::asio::execution_context&>::value>::type) [with ExecutionContext = ExecutionContext; MoveAcceptToken = MoveAcceptToken; Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol; Executor = boost::asio::any_io_executor]’
 2603 |   async_accept(ExecutionContext& context,
/usr/local/include/boost/asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp:2603:3: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:67:27: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 1 provided
   67 |     acceptor_.async_accept(
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
   68 |         [this](boost::system::error_code ec, tcp::socket socket)
      |         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   69 |         {
      |         ~                  
   70 |           if (!ec)
      |           ~~~~~~~~         
   71 |           {
      |           ~                
   72 |             std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
      |             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

   75 |           do_accept();
   76 |         });
```

My boost's version:

```
#include <boost/version.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::cout << "Using Boost "     
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
          << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
          << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
          << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

```
Using Boost 1.82.0
```

Comment: which version of boost are you using? Your code compiles with the latest version https://godbolt.org/z/45nafEMK1 and with version 1.66.0 where this overload was introduced https://godbolt.org/z/vMGh7ne6Y

Comment: @AlanBirtles i updated question. it seems 1.82.0

Comment: @AlanBirtles there is no problem with the  your tried code. i couldt use boost::asio::local::stream_protocol::acceptor in the running code. maybe you missed some point in my question

Comment: I copy and pasted your code exactly. If this isn't the code you're running please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles They posted a working program and a few modifications. Did you forget to apply the modifications?

Comment: @sehe possibly, but if people post a simple reproduction of their problem rather than code that already works it'd be clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the socket type in the session class. Abstracting a little better:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cbcbb7a7ee724ff0)**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace asio = boost::asio;
using boost::system::error_code;
// using Protocol = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using Protocol = boost::asio::local::stream_protocol;

class session : public std::enable_shared_from_this<session> {
  public:
    session(Protocol::socket socket) : socket_(std::move(socket)) {}

    void start() { do_read(); }

  private:
    void do_read() {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        socket_.async_read_some(asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                                [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t length) {
                                    if (!ec) {
                                        (std::cout << ec.message() << " '").write(data_, length) << "'\n";
                                        do_write(length);
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void do_write(std::size_t length) {
        auto self(shared_from_this());
        asio::async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(data_, length),
                          [this, self](error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/) {
                              if (!ec) {
                                  do_read();
                              }
                          });
    }

    Protocol::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server {
  public:
    server(asio::any_io_executor ex, Protocol::endpoint ep) : acceptor_(ex, ep) { do_accept(); }

  private:
    void do_accept() {
        acceptor_.async_accept([this](error_code ec, Protocol::socket socket) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::make_shared<session>(std::move(socket))->start();
            }

            do_accept();
        });
    }

    Protocol::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        if (argc != 2) {
            std::cerr << "Usage: async_echo_server <endpoint>\n";
            return 1;
        }

        asio::io_context ioc(1);

        // uint16_t port = std::atoi(argv[1]);
        // server   s(ioc.get_executor(), {{}, port});
        server s(ioc.get_executor(), argv[1]);
        ioc.run();

    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }
}
```

You can easily change everything to TCP instead by toggling the 3 commented lines